# What is the meaning of the combination あまり and たくさん into あまりたくさん?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

I came across the following sentence in my textbook (上級へのとびら, lesson 12, page 279). It is part of a presentation explaining how to make 押し花:

> まず、最初にティッシュペーパーを1枚ボール紙の上に置きます。次に、そのティッシュペーパーの上に草花を並べて置きます。この時、**あまりたくさん**置きすぎないようにして下さい。

I understand the last sentence as "this time, don't put too much/many [flowers]." But the problem is that this could be expressed already with すぎない, without the use of adverbs, couldn't it?:

> この時、置きすぎないようにして下さい。

So I don't understand what nuance あまりたくさん adds here. Moreover, if I were to add an adverb to stress the point, I would rather use only あまり with a negative verb:

> この時、あまり<strike>**たくさん**</strike>置きすぎないようにして下さい。

What meaning or nuance does たくさん add after あまり?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, この時、あまりたくさん置きすぎないようにして下さい can be deconstructed as follows:

- **置き** - put in, fill
- **たくさん置き** - put in many, fill it up

  - nice and full of flowers
- **置きすぎ** - overfill

  - don't know whether it's been overfilled by a small or large **amount**; just that it's in excess of the expected limit
- **たくさん置きすぎ** - overfilled it {a lot / with too many}

  - definitely know it's been overfilled by a large **amount**
- **あまりたくさん置きすぎない** - not overfill it very much / with so many

  - don't overfill it to such an **extent** / in excess of the limit, but still make sure its the full amount

In general speak, it's a bit like a glass of wine in a restaurant. Although the standard **amount** is 100ml, the customer wants you to fill their glass right up to the top (overfill it) but, not to the excessive **degree / extent** that the wine's spilling over everywhere on their table.

Related Expressions / Idiomatic Usage：

- できるだけ飲みすぎないようにしてください
- 顔がたくさんすぎて気持ち悪い
- 君に伝えたいことがたくさんありすぎて
- たくさんありすぎる
- 沢山すぎて
- たくさん作りすぎたソファ

There are a few points to note here:

- たくさん = lots of, many, much
- 過ぎる = too much / many of N, or over-V
- あまり～Sない = not very much / many of ～

**たくさん** is generally used to indicate the amount of something, using

- an adverb: 今年は**たくさん**雪が降った。A lot of snow fell this year.
- a noun: この部屋には机が**たくさん**ある。 There are a lot of desks in this room.

**過ぎる** can be interpreted two ways in this context - put in too many *nouns* or over-*verb*. Overfill (over-put) works better as it works better with the amount and still enables the amari~nai pattern to indicate overfill but not to excess or immoderately. As such, and it avoids the double adverb problem you mentioned - 'too too much'.

**あまり～Sない** is an adverbial pattern that is used with a negative predicate to indicate the **degree or extent** of something

- この本は**あまり**よく**ない**。　This book isn't very good.
- 鈴木さんは**あまり**食べ**ない**。 Suzuki doesn't eat much.
- 私は**あまり**速く走り**ません**。 I can't run very fast.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now that  あまり and たくさん are not joint here, but たくさん is modifying an inner clause that is inserted as a whole into the pattern あまり～Sない. However, I still don't understand the difference between 置きすぎ and たくさん置きすぎ. Is it just a matter of emphasis?

Comment: Just updated the last few lines, Cheers

Comment: The distinction between "being excessive or not" vs. "being excessive by a bit or being excessive by a lot" made it much clearer. Thanks.